# Manifest v3: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND when using chrome.runtime.getURL?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest.json, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I get a `net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` error when using `chrome.runtime.getURL` function.

#### manifest.json

```json
{
    "name": "Dummy",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "icons": {
        "16": "icon16.png",
        "48": "icon48.png",
        "128": "icon128.png"
    },
    "action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "icon16.png",
            "48": "icon48.png"
        }
    },
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "storage", "scripting"],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["*://*/*"],
            "js": ["content.js"]
        }
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        {
            "resources": ["src/images/*.jpg"],
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm using it in a `constants.ts` file which is not a service worker or content script, just a random file:

```
chrome.runtime.getURL('src/images/1.jpg')
```

But I don't get a URL but rather an error when I try to display it in a `style` tag:

```
style={{ background: `url(${chrome.runtime.getURL('src/images/1.jpg')})` }}
```

How do I solve it? I even tried opening the URL which looks like `chrome-extension://hhnlljbelglibjololeadifpojkopfk/src/images/1.jpg` in a new tab but it doesn't show anything.

How do I solve it?

Comment: It should work but there's a bug in Chrome on file:// URLs. Otherwise, maybe you forgot to reload the extension on chrome://extensions page.

Comment: @wOxxOm nope, i remove the extension & load it again. also, i have a webpack watch script running that emits the dist directory automatically & i only have to refresh the extension. any ideas on how i should solve it? i even tried the below answer before but it doesn't work either.

Comment: It means webpack doesn't know about this path and doesn't transform it, so you have to look at your `dist` directory and see the real path, then specify it here.

Comment: @wOxxOm damn, that webpack detail was accurate. thank you, posted an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oopsie, as [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) said, my `copy-webpack-plugin` wasn't copying `images` folder.

I changed my `webpack.config.js` to copy it.

```js
plugins: [
        new CopyPlugin({
            patterns: [
                { from: 'public', to: '.' },
                { from: 'src/images', to: 'images/' },
            ],
        }),
    ],
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use it in a CSS file or code line, try to use it like this:

```
style={{ background: url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/src/images/1.jpg') }}
```

For more information see this Chrome Developers page:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/i18n/#overview-predefined

Comment: i already tried it but it doesn't work